# Show modal dialog while performing an asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I'm currently trying to show a dialog while an asynchronous action is performed.

My architecture was event-based before as I want that the user can easily implement custom graphic user interfaces.

Now I'm heading for other ways, in my case return types for synchronous methods instead of EventArgs containing the data and then async-await + tasks.

Example:

```
public bool SearchForUpdates()
{
   // ...
   return true;
}
```

Now my async method should look like that:

```
public async Task<bool> SearchForUpdatesAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchForUpdates());
}
```

These methods are defined in a Manager-class.
First: Is it right that the async method awaits the synchronous one or should the synchronous one await the asynchronous one?

Then there is another class that is the interface between the Manager-class and the UI.
While there is a search for updates the relating dialog should be shown:

```
public async void ShowUserInterface()
{
    var searchDialog = new SearchDialog();
    Task<bool> searchTask = _manager.SearchForUpdatesAsync();
    IAsyncResult result = searchDialog.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => seachDialog.ShowDialog()));
    bool updatesFound = await searchTask;

    if (((DialogResult)searchDialog.EndInvoke(result)) == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        // Cancelled, do stuff 
    }
    searchDialog.Close();
}
```

That is what I thought, so there would be a way to call that and show a custom UI.
Logical problem: **Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.**

My plan seems to fail, is it maybe completely wrong? Or is there a way to show the dialog like that? There should be a way to make ShowDialog non-blocking so that I can continue and await the call. So I am actually searching for a way to call **BeginInvoke**, but I don't know where, something like **Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke** in WPF maybe, I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a main window around whose BeginInvoke() method you can use?  There must be, don't make dialogs appear from nowhere.

Comment: @HansPassant That's the point, I think. I'm calling it out of a normal class that is basically the interface between both, manager and UI. What would you suggest? As it seems I need a different architecture.

Comment: There is not an interface if your class is unaware of UI.  Which right now it is if it doesn't know anything about a main window.  Pass an argument through the constructor or a property.

Comment: Ah, you mean that the user should provide his "MainForm" basically in the constructor. Consecutively I could call "BeginInvoke" on that, right?

Comment: @HansPassant That sounds good, didn't think of that. Write an answer, so I can accept it. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you are simply using the wrong Control reference to call BeginInvoke() on.  The dialog cannot work, it wasn't created yet.  Which is important, .NET cannot figure out what thread owns the window until the window is committed to a specific thread.  Which doesn't happen until you call Show().

But any other window will do, you must already have one since it isn't legal or practical to display a dialog without an owner.  You must provide a constructor or a property so the client code can provide a reference to such a window.  Any will do, the main window of the app is a practical choice.

You can completely separate a class from the UI implementation (not practical here since you display a dialog) by copying the value of Synchronization.Current in the constructor.  On which you later can call its Post() method.  All UI class libraries in .NET install a synchronization provider that will marshal the call.

Comment: Okay, this is a good solution and I can make sure that I did everything right.
Also I don't have to change the architecture way too much, thanks.

Just one more thing that I also mentioned in the question: Is my implementation of async correct? I'm talking about the fact that the asynchronous method awaits a task that executes the synchronous function, is that ok?

Comment: Alright, thank you very much.
The only thing that is a bit of a disadvantage is that I'm maybe losing the possibility for WPF-integration. Or is there a way that the user can handle over a Windows Form or a WPF-window? If I'm not completely wrong the WPF-integration should have been possible so far, but I din't test it.

Comment: Covered by the last paragraph.

Comment: Alright, SynchronizationContext seems to work so far, but I got one problem: If there is another window displayed after "searchDialog.Close();" it will be displayed before the SearchDialog is closed and then all 2 dialogs are open. I used Post-method to show the SearchDialog.

Comment: You have some sort of new problem, you'll need to click the Ask Question button again so you can describe it properly.

Comment: Okay, I will do that.